# Getting error in console log after calling query and can't print data in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

I follow some tutorial about VueJS, Graphql and Apollo but i'm stuck.
I get this error in console log *Error sending the query 'todos' ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()*

This is my code

```
export const GET_MY_TODOS = gql`
  query getMyTodos {
    todos(where: { is_public: { _eq: false} }, order_by: { created_at: desc }) {
      id
      title
      created_at
      is_completed
  }
 }`;

  data() {
    return {
      type: "private",
      filterType: "all",
      todos: [],
    }
  },

   apollo: {
     todos: {
       query: GET_MY_TODOS,
     },
   },
```

But i must note that this query works perfectly fine i GraphiQL:
[image]

Comment: please share code as text not as screenshots